Write Matlab code which selects a "cluster" of rows satisfying a given requirement
Consider the following Matlab code:
clear
rng default
A= nchoosek(1:1:10,2);
A(:,3)=randn(size(A,1), 1);
sA=size(A,1);

The first two columns of A list all possible unordered pairs of integers between 1 and 10. The last column lists a real number for each pair. I would like to write a piece of code that does the following:

Let r be a function from {1,...,10}^2 to {1,...,sA} such that r(k,h) gives the row index of the pair (k,h) or (h,k) in A.

Set an integer M<=10 and some real number R, e.g., M=3and R=0.

Return M different integers k_1,..., k_M among 1,...,10 such that
A(r(k_i, k_j))>=R for each pair {k_i, k_j} from the M selected integers.

If such M integers do not exist, return NaN.


Example: for M=3and R=0, the code returns, for instance, {1,2,3}. Note: there can be many M different integers satisfying the requirement; the code must return just some M different integers satisfying the requirement.
See below for my attempt to write this code. It gives me memory issues when run on my actual A matrix which has 999 rows.

My (inefficient) attempt:
clear
rng default
A= nchoosek(1:1:10,2);
A(:,3)=randn(size(A,1), 1);
sA=size(A,1);

% Step 1: define function rowIndex
function rowIndex = r(k, h, A)
if k > h
    [k, h] = deal(h, k);
end
rowIndex = find(A(:,1) == k & A(:,2) == h);
end

% Step 2: Set parameters M and R
M = 3;
R = -1;

% Step 3: Construct adjacency matrix for the graph
adjMatrix = false(10, 10);
for i = 1:10
    for j = i+1:10
        if A(r(i, j, A), 3) >= R
            adjMatrix(i, j) = true;
            adjMatrix(j, i) = true;
        end
    end
end

% Step 4: Find a clique of size M
foundClique = false;
cliqueNodes = NaN;

combinations = nchoosek(1:10, M);
for i = 1:size(combinations, 1)
    subset = combinations(i, :);
    if all(all(adjMatrix(subset, subset) | eye(M)))  % Check if all pairs are connected
        foundClique = true;
        cliqueNodes = subset;
        break
    end
end

% Display the result
if foundClique
    disp('Found clique:');
    disp(cliqueNodes);
else
    disp('No clique found. Returning NaN.');
    cliqueNodes = NaN;
end


If you're stuck on step 3 and think you could implement it via a loop, it would greatly improve the question to have a [mcve] where you do exactly that, including steps 1 and 2 complete, so we can see your requirements via illustration rather than by description, and it's easy for us to suggest (and benchmark) improvements.

The problem of finding a clique is NP-complete. So there is probably not much you can do to speed up step 4 in your code, which is the most time-consuming part except for R small

Constructing the adjacency matrix can be done faster using accumarray: adjMatrix = accumarray(A(:,[1 2]), A(:,3)>=R, max(reshape(A(:,[1 2]),1,[]))*[1 1]); adjMatrix = adjMatrix|adjMatrix.';

Look at your adjacency matrix if you set all of A(:,3) to 1. It's a complete graph. You can simply skip this step, set the upper-triangular portion of the matrix to your float values, and threshold.

As for Step 4, I'd suggest trying randsample in a loop for some reasonable number of tries, at least as a first attempt. Otherwise, you would probably want to use backtracking instead of exhaustively checking all combinations.
